# Escape single quote using fireSQL

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

I am using Firebase Firestore in my Angular project and lately there is a project called fireSQL to use SQL sentence query in Firestore, it's working great, but when I try to select something where my value has a single quote it just sends an error. I try to escape using all the JavaScript techniques, but nothing happens.

**The error msg**:

ERROR

> Object { message: "Expected \"!=\", \"%\", \"*\", \"+\", \"-\", \"/\",
>   \"<\", \"<=\", \"<>\", \"=\", \">\", \">=\", \"AND\", \"GROUP\",
>   \"LIMIT\", \"OR\", \"ORDER\", \"UNION\", WHITE_SPACE, or end of input
>   but \"s\" found.", expected: (29) […], found: "s", location: {…},
>   name: "SyntaxError", stack: "" }

**and the query is**:

```js
getBrandfromSub(brand, sub) {
    const fireSQL = new FireSQL(firebase.firestore());
    return fireSQL.rxQuery(`SELECT * FROM products WHERE brand = '${brand}' AND subcategory = '${sub}'`);
  }
```

Comment: This prob won't solve your issue but surely the query you're using must pass a string to `rxQuery`? Otherwise it won't even compile.

`fireSQL.rxQuery(\`SELECT * FROM products WHERE brand = ${brand} AND subcategory = ${sub}\`);`

Comment: @Collierre Thank you for your fast replay and Yes, it should use rxQuery to fetch data from the firestore database.

Comment: Yes but I mean the code you have posted cannot be the actual code you are using because you have not passed a string parameter to `rxQuery`. Does the code you've posted look exactly the same as what you are actually working with? Or does it look like the code in my comment?

Comment: I update the post with my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the single quotes in the strings you are sending as SQL queries. The FireSQL [source](https://github.com/jsayol/FireSQL/blob/master/src/sql-parser/firesql.pegjs#L488) indicates that `\\'` is the escape sequence for `'`. So your code could do the following. (If you need to escape other special characters you'll need to add them to the `escapeSingleQuotes()` method.)

```js
getBrandfromSub(brand, sub) {
  const fireSQL = new FireSQL(firebase.firestore());
  return fireSQL.rxQuery(`SELECT * FROM products WHERE brand = '${this.escapeSingleQuotes(brand)}' AND subcategory = '${this.escapeSingleQuotes(sub)}'`);
}

escapeSingleQuotes(s: string) {
  return s.replace("'", "\\'");
}
```

Comment: Same problem and the same error message I already use this method before with the backslash method too but same result.

Comment: How about using two backslashes before the `'`? The FireSQL source indicates that `\\'` is the escaped version of `'`. https://github.com/jsayol/FireSQL/blob/master/src/sql-parser/firesql.pegjs#L488

Comment: i used before and i re used now but same problem.

Comment: i add `\\'` and then i refresh the page with CTRL + SHIFT + R to reload the cache and it work